# Enlarge UIButton's hitest area for button with background image, imageView and label in it

Tags: ios, uibutton

It may seem like duplicate, but I can't actually find any good answer to my concrete situation.
I have some button with background image (1pt-wide, streched), icon-like image inside along with the text label. It's height is 33pt, I need to make it's hittest area 44pt-high.
I saw two solutions, but neither of them works for me.

First solution is to enlarge frame and adjust image so it would have some padding. But that is not acceptable for me, because I have both background image and image inside the button.

Second solution is to subclass UIButton (which is absolutely acceptable) and override `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. I did that, when I put some breakpoints in this method and tried to tap in desired area nothing happened (breakpoints worked when tapped inside the button frame).

Are there any other solutions? What could be possibly wrong with the second solution?

Comment: Maybe you should try custom button.Or , custom view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the view programmatically, you can instantiate a UIView that is 44px high, add a tap gesture recognizer to it, and add your UIButton as a subview inside this view:

```
CGRect bigFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,44);
UIView *big = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bigFrame];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doPress)];
[big addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

UIButton *yourButton = ...
[big addSubview:yourButton];
[self.view addSubview:big];
```

Then implement the selector as:

```
- (void)doPress {
   [yourButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

In that way, the outer view taps will be interpreted as button presses for your button.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be a good alternative, though I'd really like to see some other alternatives and I still want to understand what is wrong with this `-hitTest:withEvent:` solution

Comment: Well, there's seems to be no other answers, so I'll accept yours. I ended up creating parent view and playing with `-hitTest:withEvent:` in it and it worked. All I needed was to learn better about how `-hitTest:withEvent:` works.